# Ice slide puzzle FILL ALL THE MATRIX

Tags: algorithm, fill, puzzle, sliding, ice

My problem derives from the Ice Sliding puzzle.

[image: Example]

For path finding methods, BFS is the best algorithm, but what if you want to fill all the gaps
(not rocks), in the matrix, aka visiting all cells, while doing this with the least amount of
cell visited (visiting old, or already visited cells, counts as a new visits), or the least cell traveled.

What would a possible solution be?

I was thinking of some modified BFS.
Every node of the BFS could store how many cells we have visited, and how many unique cells have been discovered, also current position.. but this seems kinda slow, and I dont know when I should tell the program to end (max n^2 moves? or idk)

Comment: "visiting all cells" ... hamiltonian?

Comment: or one rock to other rock forms one edge with distance as edge weight and path from start to end like euler path with minimum total edge weight?

Comment: So you have a two dimensional array and you want to figure out which of the items is a rock? Why not just loop through them? Or do you mean that you select some point on the map and it fills all the cells you could reach from there if you could just move around and wouldn't slide until you hit a wall? In that case, just use that algorithm that uses lines, so it pretty much draws a horizontal line from the point where it started and then just moves to the left until it hits something that isn't filled and then record when the cell above or below the current line position isn't filled

Comment: and then fill those other lines below and above. I don't quite know how that algorithm is called so I can't look it up. Also what is so time-critical about a sorta turn based game that you can't just use floodfill?